# CMake Error: Could not find include directory and library

Tags: c++, build, cmake

I am trying to build PODOFO library with CMake using MinGW compiler. It requires some external libraries like zlib, jpeg, openssl and freetype. My cmake command is as follows:

> cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles"
> -DCMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH=c:\Users\Abhishek\Downloads\freetype-2.3.5-1-bin\include -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH=c:\Users\Abhishek\Downloads\freetype-2.3.5-1-bin\lib
> -DCMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH=c:\Users\Abhishek\Downloads\zlib\include -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH=c:\Users\Abhishek\Downloads\zlib\lib -DCMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH=C:\Users\Abhishek\Downloads\openssl-0.9.8h-1-lib\include -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH=c:\Users\Abhishek\Downloads\openssl-0.9.8h-1-lib\lib
> -DPODOFO_BUILD_SHARED:BOOL=FALSE ..

Somehow it is not able to find the freetype files. The error I get is as follows:

> CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:97 (message):
>
> Could NOT find FREETYPE (missing: FREETYPE_LIBRARY FREETYPE_INCLUDE_DIR)
>
> Call Stack (most recent call first):
> C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStan dardArgs.cmake:291
> (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
> cmake/modules/FindFREETYPE.cmake:75
>
> (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS) CMakeLists.txt:372
> (FIND_PACKAGE)
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

One additional point. If I delete the previous CMake build files (cache etc) then it doesn't even find zlib!

I can't understand why this erratic behaviour. Can anyone shed light on this?

Comment: I compiled podofo library previously(about 2 years ago or so). Just create .pro file from the source code.

Answer (score 1):

When you're configuring, you need to define FREETYPE_INCLUDE_DIR and the other variables for where you keep the libraries it depends on - cmake can't guess these just from your include paths.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually I'm not much familiar with CMake. How do you that?

Comment: Since you mention MinGW, I assume you're building under windows - the easiest way is to install CMake-GUI.  Then once you hit the "configure" button, you can simply see which fields are in need of filling in, and enter their values by double-clicking on them.